# How to add support of HTML help files (.chm) on Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, html-help

How to add support of HTML help files (.chm) on Delphi XE2? We need to use A-links (A-keywords) on `HelpContext` property of every control to lookup help pages. Delphi XE2 has native support of HTML help files by unit `HTMLHelpViewer`. But how to use it?

Comment: Thanks, but if you use `HTMLHelpViewer` unit the help stops working on Delphi IDE.

Comment: have you set `Application.HelpFile := 'sample.chm';` pointing to an existing .chm file??

Comment: BPLs don't know where is .chm file.

Comment: To get sample.chm, there is a download link in my answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that to use A-links you need to do the following:

1. Assign an `Application.OnHelp` handler as described below.
2. Assign `Application.HelpFile` during program startup.
3. Call `Application.HelpKeyword` if you wish to invoke the help system with an A-link.
4. Set the `HelpKeyword` property for any GUI controls that you wish to respond to context sensitive <kbd>F1</kbd> key presses.

The `OnHelp` handler looks like this:

```
function TMainForm.ApplicationHelp(Command: Word; 
  Data: THelpEventData; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  Link: THH_AKLink;
  ALink: string;
begin
  CallHelp := False;
  Result := True;
  //argh, WinHelp commands
  case Command of
  HELP_COMMAND:
    begin
      ZeroMemory(@Link, SizeOf(Link));
      Link.cbStruct := SizeOf(Link);
      ALink := PChar(Data); // we are going to re-purpose the keyword as an A-link
      Link.pszKeywords := PChar(AnsiString(ALink)); // seems we have to pass a PAnsiChar ..
      Link.fIndexOnFail := True;
      HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow, Application.HelpFile, HH_ALINK_LOOKUP, 
        DWORD_PTR(@Link));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The `HtmlHelpViewer` unit contains methods named `LookupALink` which do the same. But I don't see how they could ever be called.

The above approach is a little bit hacky because it interprets keywords as A-Links. If you want context sensitive help, I can't see what else you can do.

Comment: But `Application.HelpKeyword` shows help by keyword (a title of help page) - not by A-link (a special code of help page).

Comment: Yep. Didn't spot that nuance. I fixed the answer. I don't think HtmlHelpViewer gets the job done. You need to write your own `OnHelp` handler. I think. I always do that anyway because `HtmlHelpViewer` is so buggy.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it now. But does `Application.HelpJump` call help with A-link too?

Comment: No. That resolves to `HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC`. In your question you say you want context sensitive help with different destinations for each control. All you have to work with are the `HelpContext` and `HelpKeyword` properties. The former is no good. It's an integer. Thus you must use `HelpKeyword`.

Comment: How to create `THelpEventData` by A-link string?

Comment: You don't. The system does it for you. Call `Application.HelpKeyword` and pass your A-link string. That will route to that event. Remember, what we have in the answer is an event handler. Just like any event handlers, you do not call them directly.

Comment: Should I add the customed `OnHelp` handler for every form on the project, bpls, dlls or only for the main form?

Comment: Delphi writes `undeclared identifier` for `HtmlHelpViewer.LookupALink`.

Comment: Our project receives WM_MYHELP message from all forms from the application and bpls: `SendMessage(Handle, WM_MYHELP, 0, DWORD(PChar(Self.HelpKeyword)));`. We need to show help by A-Link from this message.

Comment: We need only to call help with A-link string. If I pass A-link string to `Link.pszKeywords` on the code above help opens with standard lookup (not by A-link) and only with the first char of the keyword.

Comment: @Altaveron Slow down! Read the answer. "Should I add the customed OnHelp handler for every form on the project, bpls, dlls or only for the main form?" No, just to `Application.OnHelp`, as I state in the answer.

Comment: "Delphi writes undeclared identifier for HtmlHelpViewer.LookupALink" Yes. That would happen. But my answer doesn't call `LookupALink`. I merely point out that it cannot be called! Stay on course.

Comment: Er, I've no idea what `WM_MYHELP` is. Please don't expect me to read your mind. That's not in the question. I think I answered the question that you asked. This comment trail is a disaster already.

Comment: `HH_ALINK_LOOKUP` is known to work. `HtmlHelp()` is known to work. The code in the answer will connect your app to the help system and use A-links rather than keywords.

Comment: OK, there's a problem with Unicode/Ansi. That's why only the first character is used. Bear with me.

Comment: OK, the code in the answer will work. But I'd like to investigate more. I also answered at the question with the bounty. I'll put more detail there when I have it.

Comment: The actual code is incorrect. There is no `ALink` on the `TMainForm.ApplicationHelp`.

Comment: This code opens help by keyword instead by A-link for me. I don't know why. But I fixed it by setting `CallHelp := False;` on `Application.OnHelp` and by calling help manually with the same code as between `begin` and `end` inside `case`.

Comment: Hmm. The code in the answer already sets `CallHelp` to `False`.

Comment: I removed all code expept `CallHelp := False` on `OnHelp = ApplicationHelp` method. And call removed code manually. Else F1 (only F1 key) shows keyword help instead A-link help. This issue also exists if the active form is the main application form. And now I need to fix only this issue - all other works fine.

Comment: I fixed this issue by `aLink.fIndexOnFail := False;` instead `True`. But now help doesn't show for the main window. Why? A-link is correct.

Comment: Only `Application.MainFormHandle` as the first parameter for `HtmlHelp` call works incorrectly.

Comment: I don't know. I've not got your project. My simple test project works fine. Are you working with a very small and simple project?

Comment: The project is very large. But I removed all code calls help before add new one.

Comment: Try starting from an empty project. File | New | VCL Forms App.

Comment: David, do you know how just open HTML Help on the first page (without lookup)?

Comment: How do you want to identify that page? Have you found the documentation yet?

Comment: HTML Help has an issue. It never opens the first page by A-link. I checked - link is correct. But HtmlHelp() doesn't open it if `aLink.fIndexOnFail := False` and searching by index if `aLink.fIndexOnFail := True`. So I just need to open the first page without transfering A-link.

Comment: It seems, all A-links with "_" char don't work! At last I found the original issue for all other problems!

Comment: Very strange issue. A-links with '_' char don't work only for the main form. All other A-links work on the main form. All links work on other forms. (Form handler is transfered to HtmlHelp() procedure.)

Comment: Perhaps the reason why you have to convert to AnsiString is that Alinks can only use a very limited character set. Did you try URL encoding the underscore?  `'Start%5FPage'` Or is the problem not related to underscores and `Start_Page` is a Klink rather than an Alink?

Comment: I found that there is no dependency on is it main form or not. The issue depends on `_` char. It exists if I use `_` on .pas source - and there is no issue if I enter `_` on .dfm-file and read it on code.

Comment: You are right. This is not A-link. And not keyword. Something else. May be K-link (but I don't know what it is). So initial problem is that another developer trying to use this other kind of link instead A-links on some places. And all problems became from that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard with `F1` jump to a context.

Select Edit1 and press `F1` . Help opens and Overview.htm is shown.

[image]

Prerequisite.

[image]

Edit1 Help settings:

[image]

**sample.chm source settings.**

sample.ali

```
IDH_Overview=Overview.htm
IDH_welcom=FirstTopic.htm
IDH_UsingtheMenus=Overview.htm
```

sample.h

```
#define IDH_Creating_Projects_and_Topics 1005
#define IDH_Overview 1003
#define IDH_UsingtheMenus 1009
```

Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, HTMLHelpViewer, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    HHALINKLOOKUP: TButton;
    JumpAnchor: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure HHALINKLOOKUPClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure JumpAnchorClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
var
hpPath : string;
link : HH_AKLINK;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hpPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
    'HelpFile\sample.chm';
  Application.HelpFile := hpPath;
end;

procedure TForm1.HHALINKLOOKUPClick(Sender: TObject);
var
link : HH_AKLINK;
szUrl,szKey,szMsgText,szMsgTitle,szWindow : AnsiString;
begin
   szKey      := Edit1.Text; // 'UsingtheMenus';
   szUrl      :='Overview.htm';
   szMsgText  :='Error: Can''t find "'+Edit1.Text+'"!';
   szMsgTitle :='Error: HH_ALINK_LOOKUP';
   szWindow   :='main';

   with link do begin
   cbStruct    := sizeof(HH_AKLINK) ;
   fReserved   := False;
   pszKeywords := PChar(szKey);
   pszUrl      := nil;
   pszMsgText  := PChar(szMsgText);
   pszMsgTitle := PChar(szMsgTitle);
   pszWindow   := PChar(szWindow);
   fIndexOnFail:= False;
   end;
   HtmlHelpW(0, hpPath+'>main', HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, DWORD_PTR(nil));
   HtmlHelpW(0, hpPath, HH_ALINK_LOOKUP, DWORD_PTR(@link));
end;

procedure TForm1.JumpAnchorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HtmlHelpW(0, hpPath+'::/Overview.htm#'+Edit1.Text+'>main', HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, DWORD(nil));
end;
end.
```

Here is a ready to use sample.chm and the source [Download](http://moskito-x.de/stack/stackdwl1.html)

There is a trick how to easily, to jump, not only to the .htm file but jumps directly to an anchor.

Change sample.ali

```
IDH_Overview=Overview.htm
IDH_welcom=FirstTopic.htm
IDH_UsingtheMenus=Overview.htm#UsingtheMenus
```

Insert an anchor at the place, you want to jump to in **Overview.htm**

```
[...]
<A NAME="UsingtheMenus" </A>
<P><STRONG>Using the Menus and Toolbars</STRONG>
<P>The menus and toolbars provide a complete set of tools 
[...]
```

Now it is possible with `F1`, jump directly to the desired point in overview.htm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Xe2 viewer works (I'm on 2007) but I just use Eric Granges port of the Microsoft HTML help API, which unsurprisingly, is called HTMLhelpAPI.pas.

You can call an Alink using the function

ChmShowTopic(const filename,atopic:string):HWND;

Comment: No, that uses the `HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC` which is not for A-links. What's more, that port of the HTML Help API is not necessary in modern Delphi since the Delphi supplied header translation has all that's needed. That code dates from 1998!!